# Sound continues after tab close in pyqt5

Tags: browser, tabs, pyqt5

I'm making a web browser using pyqt5 just for fun and I have seen that when I close a tab the audio that was playing in that tab continue plays until I quit the browser. Any ideas how to fix that?

Edit:

```
def close_current_tab(self, i):

        if self.tabs.count() < 2:
            return

        self.tabs.removeTab(i)
```

Comment: How are you closing the tab? Do you delete the related view when it's closed? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Please don't post code in comments, [edit] the question with it. Besides, as the documentation of [`removeTab()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html#removeTab) explicitly says: "The page widget itself is not deleted.". You need to delete it.

Comment: Ok I think I understand what do you mean so based on my edited question can you please tell me how to delete the tab? (Sorry I'm noob...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the [`removeTab()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html#removeTab) documentation:

> The page widget itself is not deleted.

This means that the widget will continue to exist (and keep working in background, thus playing audio and using CPU/memory unnecessarily), even if it's not visible anymore.

In order to properly *delete* the object, you need to retrieve it *before* removing the tab (otherwise you won't get its reference anymore), and call [`deleteLater()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#deleteLater):

```
    def close_current_tab(self, i):
        if self.tabs.count() < 2:
            return
        page = self.tabs.widget(i)
        self.tabs.removeTab(i)
        page.deleteLater()
```

Note that this should be done anytime a Qt object is removed and that action doesn't specifically delete that object, so you have to always read the documentation in order to verify that.

This is obviously **extremely** important for browser pages, as they might use *a lot* of memory: a modern web page takes about 10-20mb (see the task manager of your browser), with some going up to 100-150mb for complex websites like streaming services and social networks (a Facebook home takes more than 150mb after showing just 15-20 posts); open and close a dozen of those pages without deleting them, and in a matter of seconds your program will be using more than a gigabyte of ram and a lot of CPU usage, as many websites do some processing even when not visible (dynamic updates, push notifications, video decoding, banner loading, etc.).